# In bash, how can cmd1 | cmd2 return cmd1's status code, when cmd1 fails?

Tags: bash

Simple example:

```
user:/$ find /garbage | wc -l
find: '/garbage': No such file or directory
0
user:/$ echo $?
0
```

`find` fails, but `wc` executes and `$?=0`. I would rather abort, and for `$?` to be set to `find`'s status code.

This seems to work

```
user:/$ find /garbage 2> /dev/null && if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then exit $?; fi | wc -l
user:/$ echo ?
3
```

But it's clunky and it feels like there's a cleaner, more bashonic solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from `man bash`:

> The  return  status  of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the **pipefail** option is enabled.  If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (right‐
>          most) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.  If the reserved word !  precedes a pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation  of  the
>          exit status as described above.  The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

To set it: `set -o pipefail`

Comment: Thanks! This, in conjunction with http://superuser.com/questions/510066/setting-pipefail-for-a-single-piped-command, led me to 

`nFound=$(set -o pipefail && find /garbage | wc -l)`

and I don't have to worry about affecting anyone else.

Btw...
`
user:/$ man bash | wc -l
4885
`
One of these days I'll read the whole thing!

Answer (score 4):

With current GNU bash:

Take a look at array PIPESTATUS:

```
find /garbage | wc -l
echo "find:${PIPESTATUS[0]} wc:${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
```

Output:

```
find:1 wc:0
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't quite fit my use case, but this will be useful in similar cases, when I want to find which pipe element failed. (I can get away with not caring because my 2nd cmd in the pipe is `wc`)